# How to pass variable from javascript into jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following code,

```
<a href="#" onclick="popup('<?php echo $temp_class['class']; ?>')">
```

I pass a class generated from php function to javascript function popup().

I have another code

```
  function popup (myclass) {
    $(myclass).hide();
  }
```

The variable `myclass` accept value passed to the function. How to use `myclass` value to jquery so that I can hide an html element associated with the given class like example above?

Comment: what is happening with you current code?

Comment: $('.' + myclass).hide(); incase you forgot the '.'

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to change your js code to something like this: `$('.' + myclass).hide();`

Comment: Do you want to hide all the element having specified class ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dot is used for classes so I think this will work:

```
$('.' + myclass).hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Wouter's answer a bit.

The dot class is needed for classes but it might also be worth checking if it already exists.

```
function popup (myclass) {
    if(myclass.charAt(0) === '.'){
        //If we already have a '.' just hide.
        $(myclass).hide();
    } else {
        $('.' + myclass).hide();
    }
}
```

This will make the function more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Did you think to add . to your selector ?

Because in jquery, the selector for class named myClass is .myClass like in css.